# Docker-compose: flag -p equivalence

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Let's suppose I have two web services: A and B. Both running on Apache. I want them to be accesible from different ports from my host: A from port 88 and B from port 89.

I can do it manually (by first creating the image, then running a container over that image with "docker run -p [HOST_PORT]:[EXPOSED_CONTAINER_PORT]", but, **how can I do the very same with Docker-compose?**
In other words: which would be the equivalence of the -p flag in docker-compose.yml?

Answer (score 1):

The same in docker-compose.yml is the `ports` directive. So for example:

`version: '2'
services:
 apache:
  image: your-image
  ports:
   - "88:88"
   - "89:89"`

The `apache` service definition above would expose and bind port 88 and 89 to the same port on the Docker host.

The [docker-compose.yml file reference](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/) from the official Docker documentation is pretty comprehensive and often tells you what equivalent `docker` command it maps onto.